# unit testing java servlets with binary data

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, jetty, binary-data

I'm attempting to write a Java Servlet unit test to send binary data http requests to the servlet and receive a binary response. Usually I use the jetty ServletTester and HttpTester to unit test servlets, but HttpTester doesn't seems to support binary requests yet.

Any ideas how can I unit test a binary servlet in java?

Comment: Could you not deploy the servlet inside a Jetty instance and send/receive the data over a socket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems in [Jetty 8](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/test-jetty-servlet/8.0.0.M0/org/eclipse/jetty/testing/HttpTester.java#HttpTester.0_charset) HttpTester store content in binary format.

You may extend HttpTester and set _genContent manually(it is protected). Or you can interpret the bytes as String with the same [charset](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/test-jetty-servlet/8.0.0.M0/org/eclipse/jetty/testing/HttpTester.java#HttpTester.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29) as in HttpTester.

Comment: It is an interesting idea, but I'm having difficulties to implement it. The way I use it I use HttpTester.generate() in order to make the request string that I send to ServletTester.getResponses(). My problem is that generate() return a String and I need it to return a ByteArrayBuffer(to use in getResponses()). If I want to override the generate() function as well I run into problems since it uses HttpTester private fields. 
Any ideas?

Comment: @eldadlevy it is hard to understand where your problem arises. Could you please share examples of codes in your question? Cannot unserstand why you cannot use http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty/6.1.6/org/mortbay/io/ByteArrayBuffer.java#ByteArrayBuffer.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29 to create ByteArrayBuffer before pass to Servlet.

Comment: Finally was able to do it with HttpTester: 
1. created a derived class BinaryHttpTester
2. in this class there are 2 methods -
*  setContent(byte[]) - this function stores the byte[] for later use
* ByteArrayBuffer generateBinary() - this function uses the above byte[] if was set, and the super.generate(), appends them to create a joined byte[] that is used as the request

The clients of this class first set the binary content and then use generateBinary() to get binary request. works for me